# How to use gulp.series in gulp 4?

Tags: gulp, gulp-4

Have a super simple gulp file where I want to run some basic gulp tasks in sequence one after the other.

I can't seem to get this running in Gulp v4. Had something similar in Gulp v3 using [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) instead of `gulp.series()`

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const clean = require('gulp-clean');

gulp.task('clean-app', async () => {
  return (gulp.src('./dist/app', {read: true, allowEmpty: true})
    .pipe(clean()));
});


gulp.task('clean-tests', async () => {
  return ( gulp.src('./dist/tests', {read: true, allowEmpty: true})
    .pipe(clean()));
});

gulp.task('all-tasks', gulp.series('clean-app', 'clean-tests'));
```

The individual gulp tasks `clean-app` and `clean-tests` run fine individually.

However, when I use `gulp all-tasks` i get the below error

```
gulp all-tasks
[17:50:51] Using gulpfile ~\IdeaProjects\my-app\gulpfile.js
[17:50:51] Starting 'all-tasks'...
[17:50:51] Starting 'clean-app'...
[17:50:51] Finished 'clean-app' after 10 ms
[17:50:51] The following tasks did not complete: all-tasks
[17:50:51] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Both `clean-app` and `clean-tests` return streams which I thought would be sufficient.

Have tried using [gulp4-run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp4-run-sequence)  but i get the same error.

Want to be able to run `gulp all-tasks` such that `clean-tests` is executed after `clean-app` has completed successfully.

Comment: What's your `all-tasks` task?

Comment: I updated the sample code with the correct task name. The `all-tasks` task when run produces the error shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

depending on the official documents [here](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#using-an-error-first-callback) try to run `cb()` in your tasks like that

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const clean = require('gulp-clean');

gulp.task('clean-app', (cb) => {
  gulp.src('./dist/app', {read: true, allowEmpty: true}).pipe(clean());
  cb();
});

gulp.task('clean-tests', (cb) => {
  gulp.src('./dist/tests', {read: true, allowEmpty: true}).pipe(clean());
  cb();
});

gulp.task('all-tasks', gulp.series('clean-app', 'clean-tests'));
```

Comment: tried using that @mohammad-altenji that but still gives the same error. Starting to wonder if there's some bug in the gulp-clean module im using

Comment: try to remove the clean() function and gulp-clean module to check if there is something will change!

Comment: This worked great for me as a quick dirty fix for a project where I needed to move to gulp4 (using gulp4-run-sequence)

Comment: how can i run only one task on demand, for example `>gulp clearn-app`